# how to fix this import hardhat issue

Tags: node.js, blockchain

PS D:\web 3.0\smart_contract> npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
Error: Cannot find module '../../builtin-tasks/task-names'
Require stack:

- D:\web 3.0\smart_contract\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\web 3.0\smart_contract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\cli\cli.ts:7:1)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this bug; I had it in a `hardhat` tutorial repo I had.

For me the problem came from a `yarn.lock` file that didn't specify a commit hash when yarn was specifying to install a package from github.

I blew away (`rm`'d) my `yarn.lock` files (in both the root dir and `./hardhat`) and reinstalled, and it worked.